# Separation of Variables PDE on Klein-Gordon Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

I have to use separation of variables on the 3-D Klein-Gordon equation:

$ c^2 \bigtriangledown^2 \Psi - \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial t^2}\Psi + (\frac{mc^2}{\hbar})\Psi = 0  $   where  $ \Psi (r,t) = \psi (r) T(t) $

The problems asks:

A) Use the separation of variables technique to separate th time dependence first, i.e., let $ \Psi (r,t) = \psi (r) T(t) $ and call $-\omega^2 $ the separation constant for the time equation.  Write the solution.

B) In Cartesian coordinates use the separation of variables technique on the resulting $ \psi (r) $ equation, defining the separation constants as $ -k_{x}^2, -k_{y}^2, -k_{z}^2 $ in the usual way so that each k has units of length.  Obtain the PDE in Catesian Coordinates

C) Apply the following boundary conditions to the solutions:  the solution must be zero at $ x=0 $ and $x=a$, $y=0, y=b, z=0, z=c$.  Show the new restricted from of the solutions to the PDE and the relationship between $\omega^2 $ and $ k^2=k_{x}^2+k_{y}^2 + k_{z}^2 $

Comment: What exactly have you tried to do?

Comment: I've tried separating the equation into $\psi and T$ but I'm unsure of what gradient to use.  If I let the gradient be functions of r then it becomes a spherical function, but neglecting t.  Setting the gradient as a linear combination of partials also isn't allowed so I was just curious what you guys would come up with to set up the PDE so I could see my mistake.

Comment: The coordinates you choose depend on the geometry of the system.

Comment: Part a is to solve the time dependent part which is just a second order ODE. In part b you handle the spatial part by separating it into Cartesian coordinates